# Remove duplicates but choose the old data to delete

Tags: excel, vba

I have this procedure that I have copied from a couple of forums and adapted to my needs. The procedure removes duplicates perfectly than copies my formatting as needed.

However, it is removing the new records that are duplicates and leaving me the old date.
I have a sheet with rows of data for loans and their statuses. The statuses change everyday and so I copy the new data to the next available row and then run the procedure. The procedure is leaving the old date and removing the new data as the duplicate. How can I modify so that it recognizes that the new pasted data are the duplicated records I want to keep and removes the old date as the duplicates?

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateRows()
'Demonstrates how to use the VBA RemoveDuplicates method to remove
'the duplicate rows from a particular column in a range of data.

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A11:T" & LastRow)
MyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
Range("A11:T1000" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
'pastes range with duplicates removed
Range("A11:T1000").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A11:T11").Select
Selection.Copy
'Copies formatiing
Range("A12:T1000").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24
GoToEnd
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Sort your data so the new records are above the old records.

Comment: I don't have a way of doing that, the records use the same loan number, I paste the data at the first available empty roll so it always deletes the new data.

Comment: Ok so I am now using a change (byVal) procedure that adds a date/time stampo on column U. How can I modify my code to look at that date stamp and remove the oldest records (based on column U) that have a duplicate loan number in column B?

Comment: I was able to resolve by Tim Williams' suggestion to sort data in such a way that I had to get the new data above the old data. I accomplished this by using a helper column to timestamp the data.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by Tim Williams' suggestion to sort data in such a way that I had to get the new data above the old data. I accomplished this by using a helper column to timestamp the data. 
I am not an expert (at all) so I am sure it can be written much more efficiently, but here is the full code for anyone seeking this topic:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicateRows()
'Demonstrates how to use the VBA RemoveDuplicates method to remove
'the duplicate rows from a particular column in a range of data.

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("$a$10:$u$1000")
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode 
Then
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End If

Range("a11:u1000").Select
Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("U11"), Order1:=xlDescending, Key2:=Range("B11") _
    , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:= _
    False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A11:U" & LastRow)
MyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
Range("A11:U" & LastRow).Select
Selection.Copy
'pastes range with duplicates removed
Range("A11:U1000").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A11:U11").Select
Selection.Copy
'Copies formatiing
Range("A12:U1000").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=24
GoToEnd
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```